# Macbook: Problem with ram or L bracket after ram update

Tags: mac, memory, macbook

I just updated the RAM on my MacBook from 1GB to 4GB.

When I close it up, put the battery back in and start it the sleep lamp only blinks.

When I remove the battery and ram/L bracket and only use the power cable the computer works fine. Shows that 4GB ram in "about this computer". So there is something with the ram/L bracket..

Yes, I've really pushed the memory in really hard!
My mac: 2 GHz Intel Core 2 Duo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The L-bracket isn't really an integral part except for shielding reasons; and since the RAM works properly when using the power cable, that narrows the problem down to the battery.

Make sure all of the contacts on the battery and inside of the case are clear. Does the sleep lamp blink after you press the power button, or just after putting the battery back into the case? What's the battery's power level as indicated by the status button?

You might try resetting the SMC--remove all power sources and hold down the power button for 5 seconds.

Comment: Hi NReilingh, thanks for you answer. The strange thing is that it doesnt seem to be the battery.. I can put the L bracket back.. turn on the computer and it works.. but when i screw the screws in the sleep light blinks and the screen goes black.. i can have the L bracket unscrewed, when i touch or push the screws in while the compiter is in it goes into the same mode, blinking sleep light and black screen..

Comment: NReilingh, I solved it! The padding inside the L bracket was the problem.. I removed them and replaced them with paper-tape.. Put the battery back and it started! strange! Big thanks, you pushed me to solve it ;)